# Autofac.WebApi2 Global Action FIlters injection failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

The problem I'm facing is that AutoFac does not inject the expected parameters to the corresponding filters.

I have a filter I'm using to log execution time duration for all methods in all my controllers. In order to accomplish that task I've created an ActionFilter like this:

```
//... other usings here...
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class ExecutionTimeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public Logger _logger { get; set; }

        public ExecutionTimeFilter(Logger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            _logger.Log("Log the starting time + controller + action + etc");
            actionContext.Request.Properties["Stopwatch"] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            var stopwatch = (Stopwatch)actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties["Stopwatch"];
            _logger.Log("Log the stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + controller + action + etc");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm registering my dependencies as follow:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    var container = new IocConfiguration().Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

    //This is the only way I can get the logger injected
    //This is what ideally I want to avoid
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExecutionTimeFilter(_logger));
}

//IocConfiguration
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class IocConfiguration
    {
        public IContainer Configure(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName")).As<Logger>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(httpConfiguration);

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

If I follow the steps described in the [official site](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#register-the-filter) I get the error described after the code snippet:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(c => new ExecutionTimeFilter(c.Resolve<Logger>()))
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<MyController>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

> The type 'MyController' must be assignable to
>   'Autofac.Integration.WebApi.IAutofacActionFilter'. Parameter name:
>   registration

Here is an extract of the controller:

```
//...Other usings...
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System;

namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly Logger _logger;

        public MarketoController(Logger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("path/{entityId}")]
    [ValidateEntityId]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int? entityId = null)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include the source code for `MyController` (particularly the top 30 lines).

Comment: I've completed with the controller snippet. Thanks!

Comment: Are you registering the filter provider in your Autofac builder? `builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);` Might be helpful to see your `IocConfiguration.Configure` method.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did not want to make the question extremely large. I've included all the involved components. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that your filter, `ExecutionTimeFilter`, inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`. [If you notice in the docs](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#provide-filters-via-dependency-injection) the Autofac filter mechanism *does not use the Web API action filter interfaces*.

The exception message is somewhat confusing, but I'm guessing the problem is that you're trying to use a Web API attribute filter in a registration that expects you to be using the Autofac filter interfaces.

The key step that you may have missed in the docs is the second step where it says:

> Instead of deriving from one of the existing Web API filter attributes your class implements the appropriate filter interface defined in the integration. The filter below is an action filter and **implements `IAutofacActionFilter` instead of `System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter`**.

I added some bold to the spot that's most important there.

The docs boil down to this:

- If you want to use the `Register(...).AsWebApiActionFilterFor<T>()` stuff, you need to use the Autofac filter interfaces.
- If you want to use standard Web API filters, you need to do service location because standard Web API filters don't run through dependency injection.

There is a detailed explanation in the docs as to exactly why Autofac uses custom interfaces and why DI doesn't work with standard filters.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I will have to use standard registration instead.